# Hazelcast Map is locked

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast 2.3.1, in our hazelcast.xml configuration file we
use write behind for an Hazelcast IMap:

```xml
 <map name="HazelcastObjectOperations.objectMap">
         <backup-count>1</backup-count>
         <map-store enabled="true">
             <class-name>persister.HazelcastObjectPersister</class-name>
             <write-delay-seconds>10</write-delay-seconds>
         </map-store>
 </map>
 <properties>
      <property name="hazelcast.map.cleanup.delay.seconds">5</property>
 </properties>
```

We got two classes

1. `HazelcastObjectOperation` which holds the map and is
   used to put objects into it.
2. `HazelcastObjectPersister` which extends MapStore is used
   to persist Objects when Hazelcast is calling `storeAll()`.

```java
public class HazelcastObjectOperation {

    protected final IMap<Long, MyHzcObj> objectMap;
    private final HazelcastInstance instance;

    public HazelcastObjectOperation() {
        this.instance = Hazelcast.getDefaultInstance();
        this.objectMap = this.instance.getMap("HazelcastObjectOperations.objectMap" );
    }

    public void save( final MyHzcObj object ) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        IdGenerator generator = Hazelcast.getIdGenerator("generator");
        this.objectMap.put( generator.newId(), object );
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

The Problem is when Hazelcast runs through this map and fetches the
objects which should be stored in the storeAll method of the persister
class, the map is locked for seconds and so a put into this map lasts
this time. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This was a Hazelcast issue and fixed by: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/293

By the way:
Note that it is always better to use `set()` instead `put()` if you do not need the old value. The issue was related to that `put()` tries to load old value if mapstore is defined. `set()` does not try to load old value so it is faster and cleaner.